# Problem with InfluxDB key causing GPG error during apt update

Tags: apt, gnupg

If I run an `apt update`, I get this error:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification.
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
GPG error: https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu impish InRelease:
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
NO_PUBKEY D8FF8E1F7DF8B07E
```

I read that I should run

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D8FF8E1F7DF8B07E
```

but that didn't help. By the way, I got a warning that apt-key is deprecated. So I found [this page](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/linux-package-signing-key-rotation/) at influxdata.com explaining how to configure a new key; all the commands execute without error, but it doesn't solve the problem - I still have the same error when I `apt update`.

EDIT: I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: You haven't specifically mentioned what OS/release details, but your error message is for *impish* or Ubuntu 21.10 which is EOL & thus errors can be expected; regardless questions about 21.10 are off-topic unless specific about moving to a *supported* release of Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc What has that got to do with my question? I'm on 22.04.2 LTS...?

Comment: Your paste if you read it relates to *impish* or *Impish Indri* which is Ubuntu 21.10.  The only version detail on your original question provided via paste is for the EOL release.  Why would you add a 21.10 source on a 22.04 or *jammy* system if that's what you're using?  Ubuntu 21.10 or *impish indri* is EOL & *unsupported*.

Comment: Huh - beats me. I can't say why it's there - it's been quite a while since I installed InfluxDB, and I don't remember which guidelines I followed. The question now is: What can I do to remedy this? Can I just remove it? If so, from which file? Can I just remove InfluxDB (I don't use it anymore) - would that solve the problem?

Comment: If it was my system, I'd explore why it was added & explore the logs & reason for addition (*these are mostly your own enterprises policies so we can't help there*), possibly explore what was added from it (*as it maybe a security risk!*) then remove it. It's a source; so it'll be wherever someone with `sudo` privileges added it to your system (*I'm not in your company/enterprise; why ask me?*) but it'd normally be in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (but look in the main sources if sources aren't policed strongly in your organization too). Removing the source will remove the error, not consequences

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm 100% certain that I've added this myself, perhaps because I followed a guide for an older version of Ubuntu. I've `apt remove`d InfluxDB and also removed the entries in `sources.list.d`, and `apt update` works now. Can I please ask you to rate the sensibility of this solution on a scale from "disastrous" to "reasonable"? :-)

Comment: If you removed all packages/configurations installed from that source - you've fixed almost as good as you can.  The *documentation* or *polices* are really just notes or *bread crumbs* so you have a record of what was done, thus how to cleanly remove it & not leave anything behind. Only you, or those with `sudo` rights to your machine can explore & look for clues as to what was done on your machine in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Run following command :

```
curl -fsSL https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive_compat.key | \
   gpg --dearmor | \
   sudo tee  /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive_compat.gpg > /dev/null
```

Then apt update aso.